# Echarts - On select/deselect of visual map, make a function call

Tags: heatmap, echarts

I want to create a heatmap using echarts. I was looking at [ECharts - Visual Map](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise.type). When I select/deselect a specific color in the visual map, I want call a function to show/hide the cells in the heatmap. I went through the documentation, unfortunately I was not able to find anything. Can anyone help here.